# Braintree using customized UI and PCI compliance

Tags: braintree

I am going to use braintree with cutsomized UI which takes customer credit card information either scaning card or entering credit card information.

I am also going to provide user facility of adding and replacing of existing credit card.

Should I need go for PCI compliance in this case.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like more of a design question. But when you are dealing with sensitive information like credit cards it is best to use whatever is at your disposal to maintain security. The app I made that utilized braintree's api has all of the fraud protection tools in place. If you implement PCI compliance make sure to read the section on [PCI compliance](https://articles.braintreepayments.com/reference/security/pci-compliance)

Answer (score 0):

I work as a developer at Braintree. I recommend using [Hosted Fields](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/hosted-fields/overview) so that you have the flexibility to use a custom UI while maintaining the easiest level of PCI Compliance.

You can also see how to implement the functionality of [creating users](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/customers) and adding/replacing [payment methods](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/payment-methods) in the Braintree [Guides](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/overview).